# Positioning problem with resizable div - is there a way to limit movement of .ui-resizable-se?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm hoping to implement the following resizing technique on my website to give the user the option to scale a modal. It utilizes a wrapper to trigger the scaling of the content within it.

My code is here: https://codepen.io/jsprac/pen/LoMgWm

```
var $el = $("#very-specific-design");
var elHeight = $el.outerHeight();
var elWidth = $el.outerWidth();

var $wrapper = $("#scaleable-wrapper");

// invisible wrapper is doing the resizing, so .ui-resizable-se corresponds to it... how could I limit its movement? currently, it's moving in respect to said wrapper. 

$wrapper.resizable({ 
  resize: doResize
});

function doResize(event, ui) {

  var scale;

  scale = Math.min(
    ui.size.width / elWidth,    
    ui.size.height / elHeight
  );

  $el.css({
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%) " + "scale(" + scale + ")"
  });

}

var starterData = { 
  size: {
    width: $wrapper.width(),
    height: $wrapper.height()
  }
}

doResize(null, starterData);
```

The orange box represents the .ui-resizable-se handle. I'm running into problems with its movement, as it's positioned in respect to the wrapper. For the purpose of my site, I've set the background of the wrapper to transparent; I don't want it to be visible.

To summarize: When I scale the div "very-specific-design", the .ui-resizable-se handle moves arbitrarily outside its boundaries (in correspondence to the wrapper, which the user won't see). Ideally, it'd be positioned on top of "very-specific-design" and move within its borders/not move at all. I may have to explore other options because I'm having difficulty finding a solution. (i.e. the associated jquery relies on the wrapper and, thus, the wrapper is the element that should resize).

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround; it's not the cleanest code, but through adjusting the transform CSS and positioning, it works to scale all content.

For the purposes of my project, I needed to size my divs in pixels (and not a responsive unit like vh/vw). Again, this technique resizes proportionally and regardless of positioning/using pixels!

The initial tutorial I worked off of was really helpful in accomplishing this: https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/

You can also establish additional parameters (as noted in the JQuery 'Resizeable' documentation - https://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/), such as minWidth and minHeight. The resize handle doesn't resize, so it was especially important to define minimum values so that the handle doesn't become larger than the content itself/look buggy. For the maximum values, I made it so that the content can't be resized larger than the window (with some padding). Additionally, aspectRatio must be set to true so that the handle doesn't move with the wrapper; it essentially acts as if the 'shift' key is always being pressed.

Working demo here: https://codepen.io/jsprac/pen/LoMgWm

```
$wrapper.resizable({
  aspectRatio: true, // acts as if shift key is always pressed
  // must create limits because the resize handle will remain the same! 
  minWidth: 200,
  minHeight: 200,
  // won't be able to scale as large as window
  maxWidth: windowWidth - 50, 
  maxHeight: windowHeight - 50,
  resize: doResize
});
```

I hope this helps someone, and sorry if my question wasn't very clear. It was my first post!